# STS 3.0.0 with Spring Roo 1.2.2 cannot deploy to CloudFoundry with MongoDB service

Tags: spring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, cloud-foundry

I downloaded STS 3.0.0 and have been trying to get a simple spring app onto CloudFoundry using Roo.

**STEP 1: This is my roo script**

```
// Spring Roo 1.2.2.RELEASE [rev 7d75659] log opened at 2012-08-26 22:36:52
project --topLevelPackage com.nroots.tracker
mongo setup --cloudFoundry true
entity mongo --class ~.domain.Trackable --testAutomatically 
field string --fieldName name --notNull --sizeMin 3 
field date --fieldName datetime --type java.util.Date --dateTimeFormatPattern yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS 
repository mongo --interface ~.repository.TrackableRepository --entity ~.domain.Trackable 
service --interface ~.service.TrackableService --entity ~.domain.Trackable 
web mvc setup 
web mvc all --package ~.web 
logging setup --level DEBUG --package ROOT
logging setup --level DEBUG --package PROJECT 
perform eclipse
```

**STEP 2: Import the project into STS**
I get a dialog asking me if I want to convert the legacy STS project and I select yes. The project gets imported and builds successfully.

**STEP 3:** With the roo shell still running, I modify the Trackable domain class and add a double[] array to hold gps coordinates. And then in the Package Explorer View, I do a Refactor > Push In
The project builds successfully again.

**STEP 4: Deploy to CloudFoundry**
Using the STS CloudFoundry extension, I created a new VMware CloudFoundry server and add my application and bind it to a MongoDB service...

However, I get these exceptions in the Console View during deployment:

```
2012-08-26 18:05:41,367 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trackableServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.nroots.tracker.repository.TrackableRepository com.nroots.tracker.service.TrackableServiceImpl.trackableRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trackableRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in file [/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/tracker-0-36d30b53f85ac47671b723302407a7ec/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-mongo.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDbFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.MongoServiceInfo type, but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.nroots.tracker.repository.TrackableRepository com.nroots.tracker.service.TrackableServiceImpl.trackableRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trackableRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in file [/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/tracker-0-36d30b53f85ac47671b723302407a7ec/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-mongo.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDbFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.MongoServiceInfo type, but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'trackableRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in file [/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/tracker-0-36d30b53f85ac47671b723302407a7ec/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-mongo.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDbFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.MongoServiceInfo type, but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in file [/var/vcap/data/dea/apps/tracker-0-36d30b53f85ac47671b723302407a7ec/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-mongo.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDbFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.MongoServiceInfo type, but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.MongoServiceInfo type, but found 0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.MongoServiceInfo type, but found 0
    at org.cloudfoundry.runtime.service.AbstractServiceCreator.createSingletonService(AbstractServiceCreator.java:53)
    at org.cloudfoundry.runtime.service.AbstractCloudServiceFactory.createInstance(AbstractCloudServiceFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:130)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 71 more
Stopping Tomcat because the context stopped.
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your applicationContext-mongo.xml to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  xmlns:cloud="http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd        http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring http://schema.cloudfoundry.org/spring/cloudfoundry-spring-0.8.xsd">

<mongo:repositories base-package="com.nroots.tracker"/>

<context:annotation-config/>

<mongo:db-factory
    id="mongoDbFactory"
    dbname="${mongo.name}"
    host="${mongo.host}"
    port="${mongo.port}"
    username="${mongo.username}"
    password="${mongo.password}" />

<bean class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" id="mongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Remove the line:

```
<cloud:mongo-db-factory id="mongoDbFactory"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this exception by first adding a service-name attribute:

```
<cloud:mongo-db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" service-name="my-service-name"/>
```

Where "my-service-name" is the name I set up for the MongoDB service in STS.

I then ran into an exception about the MongoTemplate constructor argument being null, which I solved by updating the cloudfoundry-runtime version from 0.8.0 to 0.8.2.

Comment: there must be something else - updating the cloudfoundry-runtime version from 0.8.0 to 0.8.2 did not solve my problem with null argument

Comment: in fact, this null argument is mongoDbFactory, so, even bean is resolved, it is null, in me case both with 0.8.0 or 0.8.2 version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Spring cannot instantiates the mongoDbFactory which binds to your CF mongo service. I assume that you have a configuration similar to the following:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>     
    </bean>

    <beans profile="default">
            <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="DB name" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" username="username" password="changeme"/>
    </beans>

    <beans profile="cloud">
        <cloud:mongo-db-factory id="mongoDbFactory"/>
    </beans>
```

Does your applications works locally?